# Codeigniter exclude file and folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

i find on stackoverflow some code. its working perfect when you exclude one folder. but i want to exclude specific folders and files. but its not excluding. Could you please help me?

```
$this->load->library('zip');
$data = array_diff(scandir(FCPATH), array('..', '.','backups'));
    // 'backups' folder will be excluded here with '.' and '..'

foreach($data as $d) {

    $path = FCPATH.$d;

    if(is_dir($path))
        $this->zip->read_dir($path, false);

    if(is_file($path))
        $this->zip->read_file($path, false);
}

$this->zip->archive(FCPATH.'backups/'.date('Y-m-d-His').'.zip');
```

this code only excluding backups folder. i want exclude  like this

Ex:

```
$data = array_diff(scandir(FCPATH), array('..', '.','backups', 'config.php', 'database.php', 'system'));
```

is it possible?

Comment: The simple way to find out is to try it. It look like it should work doesn't it

Comment: `if(is_file($path))` here you can check for file name and exclude

Comment: i try. only excluding if in path folder. its not excluding inside subfolder file. for example. i want exclude one or two files inside application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The items in the second argument that are not available in the first argument of your `array_diff()` function will not be present in the result.

You can find the documentation for the function here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but i need code. i try from this all for files. i can not...

Comment: its working. but excluded only backups folder. system, config.php and database.php not excluding.

Comment: Are you saying that `$data` in your bottom example still contains a string 'config.php' or 'database.php'? Because that is not what I get and not the expected behaviour of `array_diff()`

Answer (score 0):

i found solution with exec system.  here is my code.

```
$zippath = "/home/domainname/public_html/";    
$makezip= exec("zip -r ".$zippath."backup.zip ".$zippath." -x ".$zippath."system/* -x ".$zippath."application/config/* -x '*.zip' -x 'database.php'");
            if($makezip) {
                echo "Zip archive done!";
            } else {
                echo "Some Problem";
            }
```

- -x = exclude
- -x system/* = if you put after folder its mean exclude all files inside folder.
- -x *.zip = mean exclude only zip files.
- -x 'database.php' = mean exclude if have database.php inside any folders.